# Basic HTML table formatting for email

Tags: html

I am making a simple newsletter layout that can only contain basic HTML but am getting caught up on formatting it properly. I have very little html experience, if I could use css I could lay this out but this is meant to be low level html that most e-mail clients can display properly.

This is a bit of code that I've done to get the image and a button (in the position of button 2) looking correct but it's getting the top and bottom buttons sitting there correctly that's the issue.

```
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center;">
 <td>
 <img src="http://localhost/temp/leftpic.png"></td>
<td>
 <img src="http://localhost/temp/button.png"></td>
</table>
```

This is my design outcome. With the outter border being a table border centered in the middle of the page.

[image]

Is it possible to format something relatively close to this without using css?

I appreciate any help, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN use css, you just have to avoid third-party files. You need to define the CSS rules inline, that is, in the `style` attribute, as you are already doing it for `table`. However, your HTML is invalid. You need to have `tr` elements outside your `td` elements and it is healthy to actively wrap your `tr` elements inside a `tbody`, which should be the child of your `table`.

By the way: the reason one should avoid third-party css in this case is that it might mess the design of the page of gmail/yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will start you off... This is with no CSS and no styling (other than what you have originally).

Although you state no CSS yet your first line is styling (albeit inline). Did you just mean no external file?

This is how we used to do layout before CSS, so this is using HTML tables:

```
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center;"  border="1">
    <tr>
 <td width="50%">
         <img src="http://localhost/temp/leftpic.png" width="390" height="480" />
     </td>
<td>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="bn1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="bn2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="bn3" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Since you have a fixed height of your image on left, you can also use

```
<tr height="160">
```

Since 160 * 3 = 480 (the height of your image)

See an example here https://jsfiddle.net/on6ytfyn/

You probably want to remove the border in the first line of code too.

Comment: This was exactly what I was after. Yeah that first styling part shouldn't be in my code, was a mistake. I'll use this as a template and go from here with changing it to what i need. Styling wasn't explicitly forbidden I was just trying to use the bare minimum. Thank you!